# How can I ensure that newest version of Gradle resolve all dependencies

Tags: spring, gradle

I need to update Gradle version in kotlin project. Have I any option to check if all dependencies support new version of Gradle or I need to check all dependencies release nots to make sure.
Actually for me it's not pretty clear how dependencies can't support new version of Gradle.
For instance: [image: Spring Boot docs]

Comment: That has nothing to with dependencies but is related to the `spring-dependency-management` plugin.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have read a release note of one library [link](https://github.com/commercetools/commercetools-sync-java/blob/master/docs/RELEASE_NOTES.md#810---dec-14-2021) and I notice `Migrated from gradle v6.8.2 to v7.3.1.`

Comment: Your mention of those release notes in your comment makes your question even more confusing.  The release notes are for a Java library that seems to have nothing to do with Gradle.  I believe that the release notes you cite reference Gradle only to mention what version of the tool was used to package the library.  You shouldn't care about that. I'd suggest that you leave your Gradle version what it is unless you have some reason to upgrade it (ie: something's broken).  If you do, then you do.  In that case, test all the build cases you can think of (I expect that they'll all work) and move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Have I any option to check if all dependencies support new version of Gradle

There two sets of dependencies:

1. Application dependencies -- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html

Applications dependencies have no correlation with Gradle whatsoever. These are dependencies needed to build your application and has no impact on Gradle's build environment.

2. Build dependencies

   - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:build_script_external_dependencies
   - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html

These dependencies, commonly Gradle plugins, do have an impact of your build. Whether or not a plugin supports a version of Gradle is only known by going to the source and checking release notes, if any. If it is not clear if a plugin supports a particular version of Gradle, then your only option is to upgrade your version of Gradle and see if anything breaks.